# Slim controller function missing argument 1

Tags: slim

I have simple Slim app that should render a html page.
This is my index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \RKA\Slim(
    [
        'mode' => 'development',
    ]
);
// Optionally register a controller with the container
$app->container->singleton('App\Home', function ($container) {
    return new \App\Controller\Home();
});
// Set up routes
$app->get('/','App\Home:index');
```

This is my controller Home.php
namespace App\Controller;

```
class Home
{
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    public function index($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->app->render('../test.html');
    }
```

I get `Message: Missing argument 1 for App\Controller\Home::index()`

Comment: Are you using Slim 2 or Slim 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're not using original Slim, but Slim extended using the [RKA Slim Controller project](https://github.com/akrabat/rka-slim-controller).

As far as I understand the code, your `index` will not get the app passed as param. The method will get only URL params that the route defined (in this case none).

If you need reference to the app, implement method named `setApp`, that will be called automatically (when dispatching the route).

```
class Home
{
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $app;

    public function setApp($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function index() {
        /* logic for the route
           app is available as $this->app */
    }
}
```

If you additionally implement `setRequest` and `setResponse`, you will get the request and response references.